# Can I use it is time to go back to in a formal academic essay?

Tags: writing

First, The Islamic revolution occurred in 1979, bringing a whole set of radical conservative changes to a once liberal westernized Iran. Second, One of these changes was the enforcement of veils and cosmetic modesty on woman, who were forbidden to show a single strand of hair, or apply a single dash of makeup on their faces. Furthermore, the changes that resulted from the Islamic revolution also included the comprehensive revision of the education system to a more conservative one to suit the contemporary belief systems. That being said, it is time go back to the root of the islamic revolution, which started with the overthrow of the Shah and the beginning of the Al-Khomeini ruling.....

Is it informal for me to use It is time to go back to ? Can anyone suggest a better transition? (That being said, it is time go back)

Comment: I would consider it too informal. I think a new paragraph, without using such a transition, would be better.

Comment: I agree with @Stefan.  I also think “That being said” is in the same  category.

Comment: If you want to sound conversational, just go on ahead. If you want to sound professional, use a pause instead. If a paragraph break seems to be too short a pause to convey a change of context, a chapter break will certainly do the trick.

Comment: First, "it is time go back to" --> "it is time **to** go back to"  Rather than use the above, I'd probably start another paragraph instead. Something along the lines of "The roots of that revolution can be traced back to the 1953 American-British overthrow of Mosaddeq, Iran's Prime Minister...."